# Cannot click off settings dropdown in profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, next-privilege

I have found a small bug in the profile page - if you click on the settings button under the reputation graph (the one where you select either privilege or tag badge to be tracked) you cannot click off the dropdown without selecting one of the , or re-clicking on the gear icon. This is unlike the behaviour of the tag badge settings button.  Please could we fix this bug?

[image]

Note: The one settings modal I am talking about is the **second** one being clicked on in the video - the topmost settings button.

Also, if this happens, could we do this for all other dropdowns/dialogs that exist on SO?

Comment: It's a dropdown, not a dialog, so it's not surprising that it behaves differently. :) Having said that, I agree that it'd be a nice to have to be able to dismiss it by clicking elsewhere.

Comment: I agree that it's a dropdown. Unfortunately, the SE UI doesn't really do a good job of differentiating the look of a dropdown from other types of dialogs. In addition, dropdowns are rarely used relative to how often users see other dialogs. As a result, users have been generally trained that they can click outside of the dialog to dismiss it. It would be quite reasonable to implement that here, and in any other dropdowns that look like dialogs.

Comment: You can also normally click outside of dropdowns to cancel them, so I'm not sure why it _wouldn't_ have this behavior if it's a dropdown.

Comment: It may have been excluded, as the other dialogs on the profile page are dialogs, not drop downs.